# How to read the multiple CSV files generated at one go dynamically in Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

We want to read the multiple CSV files generated at one go dynamically through Oracle PL/SQL or Oracle Proc (for one of our requirement) and we are looking some pseudo code snippets or logic to build the same.

We searched for the same but no luck. This requirement has to be done purely through Oracle and no Java is involved here.

Comment: Where are the files - on a client or on the DB server, and somewhere you have (or can have) an Oracle directory object that can see them? What are you doing with the data in the files; and is the data in the files the same format - same fields in the same order?

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with this problem in the past, and what I did was to write a (quite easy) parsing function similar to `split`. It should accept two variables: String and separator. It then returns a array of strings.

You then load the whole file into a text variable (declared big enough to hold the whole file) and then invoke the split function (with EOL as separator) to split the buffer into lines.

Then, for each line, invoke the parser again using comma as separation.

Though the parser is simple, you need to take into account possible conditions (e.g. bypass blanks that are not part of a string, single/double quotes management, etc.).

Unfortunately, I left the company at which the parser was developed, otherwise I would had post the source here.

Hope this helps you.

**UPDATE: Added some PSEUDO-CODE**

For the Parser:

This mechanism is based on a **state-machine** concept.

1. Define a variable that will reflect the *state* of the parsing; possible values being: BEFORE_VALUE, AFTER_VALUE, IN_STRING, IN_SEPARATOR, IN_BLANK; initially, you will be in state BEFORE_VALUE;
2. Examine each character of the received string and, based on the character and the current state;
3. It is up to you to decide what to do with blanks like in `aaa,bbb,   ccc,ddd`, those before `ccc` (in my case, I ignored them).
4. Whenever you start or go through a value, you append the character to e temporary variable;
5. Once you finished a value, you add the collected sub-string (stored in the temporary variable) to the array of strings.
6. The state machine mechanism is needed to properly handle situations like when you have a comma as part of a string value (and hence it is not possible to simply search for commas and chop the whole string according to them),
7. Another point to take into account is empty values, which would be represented by two consecutive commas (i.e. in your state machine if you find a comma when your state is IN_SEPARATOR, it means that you just passed an empty value).

Note that exactly the same mechanism can be used for splitting the initial buffer into lines, and the each line into fields (the only different is the input string, the separator and the delimiter).

For the File handling process:

1. Load the file into a local buffer (big enough, preferable CLOB),
2. Split the file into records (using the above function) and then loop through the received records,
3. For each record, invoke the parser with the correct parameters (i.e. the record string, the delimiter, and `','` as separator),
4. The parser will return you the fields contained in the record with which you can proceed and do whatever you need to do.

Well, I hope this helps you to implement the needed code (looks complex, but it is not; just code it *slowly* taking into account the possible conditions you may encounter when running the state-machine.

Comment: Hi FDavidov.. thanks for the reply. I am looking for generic SQL function. The approach suggested is more towards Java. Please let know how to achieve in Oracle

Comment: What I described was fully developed in PL/SQL (i.e. Oracle), and is as generic as it can be.

Comment: By the way, I missed one parameter for the parser; It should accept three parameters: (1) Input string, (2) Separator Character, like comma, and (3) Delimiter character (for strings).

Comment: One more thing about my development, it performed beautifully :-).

Comment: As I stated, no access to the code (left the company few months ago). Pseudo-code... I'll try to add something to my answer, but do not expect a step-by-step thing.

Comment: What is the advantage of writing your own PL/SQL code to do this, over using external tables?

Comment: Well, you mentioned/suggested that you want it to be as flexible as possible. The use of external tables requires "definitions" of the tables and mapping of the input to the output. In my approach you don't need any definition of tables. Simply load the data and deploy it. Also, since the whole file is loaded in one shot (which might not be the case for a CSV-based table), performance may be improved (again, if the file is not too big, the different will be negligible). Last, I very much liked coding it and see it performing.